# Проверка нахождения курсора на другом элементе

Tags: javascript

Мне надо, что-бы в этом обработчике, проверялся находится ли курсор на другом элементе?

```
 document.getElementById('wrapper_photo').onmousemove = function(){
    // Как сделать, что-бы этот обработчик проверял находится ли курсор на другом элементе
  }
```

Я сделал так

```
          var ar = {
     top: 0,
     bottom: 0
     }

     document.getElementById('top_line').childNodes[1].onmouseover = function (){
         ar.top = 1
         }
     document.getElementById('bottom_line').childNodes[1].onmouseover = function (){
          ar.bottom = 1
 }
 document.getElementById('top_line').childNodes[1].onmouseout = function (){
         ar.top = 0
         }
     document.getElementById('bottom_line').childNodes[1].onmouseout =               function (){
          ar.bottom = 0
 }

 document.getElementById('wrapper_photo').onmousemove = function(){
    if(photoFunc.receiver == 1){
        var mouse_x = event.clientX
        var a = window.innerWidth / 2
        if(mouse_x < a) {
            if(ar.top == 0 && ar.bottom == 0){
            document.getElementById('go_slide').style.opacity = '0.3'
            document.getElementById('back_slide').style.opacity = '1'
            }}
        if(mouse_x > a) {
            if(ar.top == 0 &&  ar.bottom == 0){
            document.getElementById('go_slide').style.opacity = '1'
            document.getElementById('back_slide').style.opacity = '0.3'
            }}
        if(ar.top == 1 || ar.bottom == 1){
            document.getElementById('back_slide').style.opacity = '0.3'
            document.getElementById('go_slide').style.opacity = '0.3'
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Торопитесь?

     Мне надо, что-бы в этом обработчике, проверялся находится ли курсор на другом элементе?

Может быть и надо. Я затрудняюсь ответить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Событие onmousemove возникает, когда пользователь перемещает курсор мыши в пределах элемента #wrapper_photo. Соответственно, когда курсор на другом элементе - данное событие у вас не возникнет. Используйте событие **onmouseout**.

Comment: у меня элемент находится внутри того у которого возникает onmouseover

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать не **onmousemove** а **onmouseover**

Comment: да мне внутри этого onmousemove надо проверить onmouseover или onmouseuout другого элемента

Comment: ну так и используйте эти функции внутри "этого onmousemove"

document.getElementById('другой элемент').onmouseover = function(){//code}

Comment: разве это нормально?